# XML : Add Nodes in between the specific Node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

This is my xml doc:

```
<FolderSettings>
<quantity>0</quantity>
<FolderList>
   <Folder>
    <FolderName>E:\05.09.2016</FolderName>
    <Checked>true</Checked>
  </Folder>

  <Folder>
    <FolderName>E:\100CANON</FolderName>
    <Checked>true</Checked>
  </Folder>

  <Folder>
    <FolderName>G:\Sony</FolderName>
    <Checked>true</Checked>
  </Folder>

</FolderList>
```

I want to add Folder node with 2 notes into the FolderList node.

```
<Folder>
   <FolderName>E:\Nikon</FolderName>
    <Checked>true</Checked>
  </Folder>
```

Every time I select/add a folder, which one is added as a node into FolderList?

How can I do this? I tried something that almost failed.

this is my code for added note into FolderList node

```
        Dim xmlFile = XDocument.Load(PXmlFileName)
        Dim element = <Folder>
                          <FolderName><%= _folderPath$ %></FolderName>
                          <Checked><%= "true" %></Checked>
                      </Folder>
        Dim parent = xmlFile...<FolderList>.FirstOrDefault()
        parent.Add(element)
        xmlFile.Save(PXmlFileName)
```

Thanks

```vb
Public Function UpdateFolderListsIntoXML(_folderPath$) As Boolean
    Dim _xdoc As New XDocument()
    Try
    'Loading: 
        _xdoc = XDocument.Load(PXmlFileName)
        Dim _lamIsElementExists = Function(_elementName$)
                                      Dim _folderlistElement As XElement
                                      Try
                                          _folderlistElement = _xdoc.Root.Element(_elementName$)
                                          If Not IsNothing(_folderlistElement) Then
                                              Return True
                                          Else
                                              Return False
                                          End If
                                      Catch ex As Exception
                                          Return False
                                      Finally
                                          _folderlistElement = Nothing
                                      End Try
                                  End Function
        If _lamIsElementExists("FolderList") = False Then
            'create FolderList element
            _xdoc.Root.Element("FolderSettings").Add(<FolderList>
                                                     </FolderList>)
            _xdoc.Save(PXmlFileName)
            'After Create "FolderList" Element loading xml file again
            _xdoc = XDocument.Load(PXmlFileName)
        End If
        'Add New Path into FolderList Element
        Dim element = <Folder>
                          <FolderName><%= _folderPath$ %></FolderName>
                          <Checked><%= "true" %></Checked>
                      </Folder>
        Dim parent = _xdoc...<FolderList>.FirstOrDefault()
        parent.Add(element)
        _xdoc.Save(PXmlFileName)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        PeX = ex
        Return False
    Finally
        _xdoc = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

this is working fine for me... i appreciate for any suggestion thanks

Comment: Show what you´ve tried

Comment: element = <Folder>
                          <FolderName><%= _folderPath$ %></FolderName>
                          <Checked><%= "true" %></Checked>
                      </Folder>
            Dim parent = xmlFile...<FolderList>.FirstOrDefault()
            parent.Add(element)
            xmlFile.Save(PXmlFileName)

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you used, it makes it a lot more readable. Also judging by your comment, you could find the element before which it needs to be inserted and use `AddBeforeSelf`

Comment: Your code is working for me. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: omg :O ... really thanks .. please delete the FolderList node into xml doc then please try

Comment: _this is working fine for me... i appreciate for any suggestion thanks_ - if so, then this question is more for [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you extract your lambda to the function it will be little bid easy to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use Append and not Add.. like in this example that i have found online:

```
' create new instance of XmlDocument
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

' load from file 
doc.Load(filename)

' create node and add value 
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "FolderList", Nothing)
'node.InnerText = "this is new node";

' create title node 
Dim nodeTitle As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("FolderName")
'add value for it
nodeTitle.InnerText = "G:\Sony"

' create Url node 
Dim nodeUrl As XmlNode = doc.CreateElement("Checked")
nodeUrl.InnerText = "True"

' add to parent node 
node.AppendChild(nodeTitle)
node.AppendChild(nodeUrl)

' add to elements collection 
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node)

' save back 
doc.Save(filename)
```

Comment: Please provide the error message or the part of code that dont work!

Comment: your codes create duplicate FolderList element then stored append values
i want to add Folder element into FolderList element everytime

Comment: This code was just an example, you must edit as you like. Set the parent node here `Dim node As XmlNode`

Comment: thanks for your tip finally i changed my codes to working but not optimized i updated my question now

Comment: You are welcome! If i have helped you, please click on the green check below the "up and down vote" at the left of my answer! ;)